# Installing scipy.spatial with ArcPy gives DLL load failed error on import?

Tags: arcpy, installation, scipy.spatial

I am running python 2.7.6 from an ArcGIS installation. I have tried to install scipy from the Python Exchange Packages [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), using the scipy-0.14.0.win32-py2.7.exe executable. I get no error importing scipy, but when I try to import scipy.spatial I get the following error:

```
In [1]: import scipy

In [2]: import scipy.spatial
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6f8fbf892cc9> in <module>()
----> 1 import scipy.spatial

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py in <module>()
     89 from .kdtree import *
     90 from .ckdtree import *
---> 91 from .qhull import *
     92 from ._plotutils import *
     93

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Anyone had success install scipy with spatial functions on top of Esri's Python site-package (ArcPy)?

Comment: I have successfully used both together.  Are you running 32bit or 64bit Python (e.g. which one is on your PATH environment variable)?  What about installing scipy via PIP?

Comment: No, PIP didn't work, or easy_install. Lots of errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version of `scipy` that Christolph Gohlke has (very kindly) compiled is compiled against the version of `numpy` he's compiled with the against the Intel Math Kernel Library. This is different to the version of `numpy` that's released with ArcGIS, and as such won't work with the ArcGIS installed version.

Instead if you download `scipy` from the official [SourceForge repository](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/latest/download?source=files) it should work.

Comment: That's it! I had noticed that at first, but had installed the version of numpy that Christolph compiled against as a solution. That caused other issues apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the scipy supplied by ArcGIS depends on DLL's loaded by arcpy. So if you do

`import arcpy
import scipy.spatial`

Then the error seems to go away.  Without importing `arcpy`, you get this error.

Alternatively, if you add the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\bin to your PATH, then the scipy libraries will find the arcpy DLL's that are needed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.